# How can i drag and drop multiple widgets at the same time i can drag my labels but want to drag them at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def vp_start_gui():
    root = Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)

root.mainloop()

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):

        top.geometry("300x300")
```

I use all of your funtions they work great the way you had them but if I put it a class is doesent work well

if I select individually it jumps about half a screen
            def select_and_drag(widgets_list):
                """Drags all the widgets together 
                in the given list with mouse point.

```
            Args:
            widgets_list (list, tuple): Takes list of widgets 
                to be moved together."""

            def set_drag(evt):
                """Set iniitial points."""
                for w in widgets_list:
                    w._drag_x = evt.x 
                    w._drag_y = evt.y

            def on_drag(evt):
                """Drags with mouse."""
                for w in widgets_list:
                    x = w.winfo_x() - w._drag_x + evt.x
                    y = w.winfo_y() - w._drag_y + evt.y
                    w.place(x=x, y=y)

            for wid in widgets_list:
                wid.bind("<Button-1>", set_drag, '+')
                wid.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag, '+')

        self.Label1_3 = Label(top)
        self.Label1_3.place(relx=0.687, rely=0.183, height=36, width=124)
        self.Label1_3.configure(text='''Height''', bg="brown")

        self.Label1 = Label(top, text="try")
        self.Label1.pack()

        select_and_drag((self.Label1_3, self.Label1))
        select_and_drag((self.Label1,))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: Do you want to select, drag and drop or you want to drag and drop all those 3 labels together?

Comment: I want to drag and drop  those all together if possible , without selecting each

Comment: Yes, I realize that. That's not what I asked. Are these the only three widgets you want to drag together, or will your actual program have many widgets that can be dragged? The solution to specifically dragging _only_ these three widgets is different from being able to drag some other group of widgets. In other words, do you need a general purpose  solution for dragging multiple widgets, or a solution that works only for this very specific case of three widgets?

Comment: This is not the right way of asking a [follow-up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/10364425), please rollback to the previous question and ask another question referring to this post so one can see and under your issue properly.

Comment: Ok sorry ..I played around with it for a bit and I realized that if I use .place  I have to use .grid or pack is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: You can use just the place manager... I'm not getting what you're trying to say properly.

Comment: If I use the place manager and have multiple widgets selected they fly off the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and you are almost there with your code. I just modified and improved your drag functionality, I made one function `select_and_drag(widget_list)` which takes a list of widgets and makes a set of them together, which means moving one widget will make all the widgets in that set move along.

*Here is the function.*

```py
def select_and_drag(widgets_list):
    """Drags all the widgets together 
    in the given list with mouse point.

    Args:
        widgets_list (list, tuple): Takes list of widgets 
                to be moved together."""

    def set_drag(evt):
        """Set iniitial points."""
        for w in widgets_list:
            w._drag_x = evt.x 
            w._drag_y = evt.y

    def on_drag(evt):
        """Drags with mouse."""
        for w in widgets_list:
            x = w.winfo_x() - w._drag_x + evt.x
            y = w.winfo_y() - w._drag_y + evt.y
            w.place(x=x, y=y)

    for wid in widgets_list:
        wid.bind("<Button-1>", set_drag, '+')
        wid.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag, '+')
```

---

*How to use it?*

More than one set can be created with different widgets from this function. You can get an idea from this **example** below, move each ***SET*** and see for yourself.

```py
from tkinter import *

root  = Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

# SET 1
lbl1 = Label(root, text='SET1', fg='red')
lbl1.pack()
lbl2 = Label(root, text='SET1', fg='red')
lbl2.pack()

# Common for SET1 and SET3
lbl3 = Label(root, text='SET1 and SET3', 
             bg='pink', fg='red') 
lbl3.pack()

# SET2
lbl4 = Label(root, text='SET2', bg='lightblue')
lbl4.pack()
lbl5 = Label(root, text='SET2', bg='lightblue')
lbl5.pack()

# SET2
lbl6 = Label(root, text='SET3', bg='pink')
lbl6.pack()

# Make SETS.
select_and_drag((lbl1, lbl2, lbl3))
select_and_drag((lbl4, lbl5))
select_and_drag((lbl3, lbl6))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've  trying to figure out out for so long now

Comment: @Jacob: I'm glad it helped. I forgot to add `"+"` in both the bind now I fixed it so update it in your code as well.

Comment: hey can you check my could again please I'm kinda new with stackoverflow so I just edit my whole code ..if I wanna drag the labels one of them just flies of the screen

Comment: @Jacob: I can’t run your code, please do not edit any well answered question. If you have a question related then ask a follow up question referring to the previous question.